# Is it possible to assign typealias for 2D dimension array in Swift? typealias MatrixT<T> = [[T]]

Tags: arrays, extension-methods, type-alias, swift5

I'd like assign typealias for 2D generic array. (*I don't want to create new type `struct MatrixT<T>{}`*). So I do next:

```
typealias MatrixT<T> = [[T]]
```

But when I started write extension for it I found that compiler actually doesn't understand that `MatrixT` is **2D** array. It recognizes type of `self` as `[Element]`

```
extension MatrixT {
    var columnsCount: Int {
        let copy = self \\compilator recognizes this as let copy: [Element] = self
        let row = self[0] \\compilator recognizes this as  let row: Element
        return 0
    }
}
```

But outside of the extension the Swift compiler understands that element of `MatrixT` is array.

```
func testCreation() {
    let matrix: MatrixT = [[0]]
    let firstRow:[Int] = matrix[0] \\ correct
    let columnsCount = firstRow.count
}
```

Why I can't refer to type `MatrixT` in the extension as to **2D** array (`[[T]]`)?

Answer (score 0):

typealias is an alias for existing type.  Here it refers to array of something.  If you look at the definition of an Array, it is

```swift
public struct Array<Element>
```

that Element happens to be an array.  Extending yours, for the following definition

```swift
typealias MatrixZ<Z> = [[[Z]]]

extension MatrixZ {

    var someCount: Int {
        let copy = self
        let row = self[0]
        return 0
    }
}
```

here also it happens to be Element which is 2 dimensional array.